# Finding the Laurent series for $1/(1-\cos z)$ in the $2\pi n < |z| < 2\pi (n + 1)$ annulus.

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

I wan to obtain the Laurent series of the $f(z) = 1/(1-\cos z)$ in some annulus 
$2\pi n < |z| < 2\pi (n + 1)$, for some integrer $n$.

Given that $f(z)$ has poles at $2 \pi n$, 
I figured I can set up my expansion in the region where $z > 2 \pi n$ as
\begin{align}
f(z) 
&= \frac{2}{(z - 2\pi n )^2} 
\left( 1 + \frac{(z - 2 \pi n )^2}{12} + \frac{(z - 2 \pi n )^4}{240} \ldots \right) \\
&= \frac{2}{z^2\left(1 - \frac{2\pi n}{z} \right)^2} 
\left( 1 + \frac{(z - 2 \pi n )^2}{12} + \frac{(z - 2 \pi n )^4}{240} \ldots \right)
\end{align}

Assuming I am interested only in the principal part of the series, 
I can focus only on the first term above and by expanding I get

$$ \frac{2}{z^2\left(1 - \frac{2\pi n}{z} \right)^2} = 
\frac{2}{z^2} \left( 1 + \frac{4\pi n}{z} + \frac{12\pi^2 n^2}{z^2} + \ldots \right).$$

And by now, I thought I was done, and that I can simply identify the coefficients of the principal part of the series as $a_{-1} =0$, $~a_{-2} = 2$, $~a_{-3} = 8\pi n$, $~a_{-4} = 24\pi^2 n^2$, and so on.

However, I wanted to cross-check this using the integral formula for the Laurent coefficients,
$$
a^I_{k} = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{\mathcal C} ~ z^{-1-k} \frac{1}{1 - \cos z} dz,
$$
where the contour $\mathcal C$ can be chosen as a circle of the radius 
$(2n+1) \pi$ around the point $z =0$.

And now comes the confusing part; these do not match (except when $n=0$)! 
Can you imagine my dismay?! Where did I go wrong with the expansion?

Experimenting (numerically) with the integral formula, I found that even $a_{-2}$ should know on which annulus I am on (it should depend on $n$), but somehow my expansion above does not see that. Something must have gone wrong when constructing the series...

**Edit**

Ok, experimenting further with the coefficients from the integral formula $a_n^I$, I found the following relation to the coefficients obtained from the
direct expansion

$$ a_k^I = \sum_{m = -n}^n a_k(n),$$

where $n$ keeps track of the radius of the integration contour. 
So it seems I need to sum over all the poles within the integration contour, 
to get the coefficient in $n-$th annulus. Why is that the case?

Comment: You have the expansion of $(z - 2 \pi n)^2/(1 - \cos z)$ on $|z - 2 \pi n| < 2 \pi$, not on $2 \pi (n - 1) < |z| < 2 \pi (n + 1)$. Regarding your last formula, essentially you have subtracted the singular part by considering
$$\frac 1 {1 - \cos z} - \sum_{|k| \leq n} \frac 2 {(z - 2 \pi k)^2}.$$
The result is regular on $|z| < 2 \pi (n + 1)$. So to get the principal part of the Laurent series of $1/(1 - \cos z)$ on $2 \pi n < |z| < 2 \pi (n + 1)$, you can sum the expansions of $2/(z - 2 \pi k)^2$ on their common domain $|z| > 2 \pi n$.

Comment: Thanks! Ok, I understood the latter part, just didn't quite get the first sentence (or maybe just the reason for it). Why is expanding $(z-2\pi n)^2/(1-cos z)$, as I did above, suspect? Regarding the latter part, is there a way to figure out what the remaining regular part looks like, once I subtract all the poles? Thanks again for the help!

Comment: An expansion on an annulus $a < |z| < b$ has the form $\sum_{k \in \mathbb Z} c_k z^k$. All the $c_k$ will contribute to the result when you multiply two series. As for the regular part, the integral can be evaluated by finding the residues at the poles. The pole at $0$ is not simple, so the series expansion of $1/(1 - \cos z)$ at $0$ is required. Faa di Bruno's formula gives
$$\frac {z^2} {1 - \cos z} =
2 + 2 \sum_{n \geq 1} \sum_{1 \leq k \leq n}
 (-2)^k k! B_{n, k}(a_1, \ldots, a_{n -k + 1}) \frac {z^n} {n!}, \\
a_j = \frac {\cos \frac {\pi j} 2} {(j + 1) (j + 2)}.$$

Comment: Thanks! If you copy these texts in an answer section I can checkmark it as answered.